# Rails - Redirect_to error in controller - "The page isn't redirecting properly" "

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, controller

In the process of learning Rails so excuse my noob question.

What I want to do:
There is a text_field_tag that allows a user to enter an item id. I then want to get that value and use it as a parameter in the url. 
ex.
The user types '4Qe6' into the text box and clicks submit. Then the page navigates to 'trckr.net/tracker/track/4Qe6'

Here is the code for my form:

```
<h1>Tracker#index</h1>
<p>This is the landing page</p>
<p>
  <u> Track an item: </u>
  <%= form_tag(:action => 'track') do %>
    Item ID: <%= text_field_tag(:id) %>

    <%= submit_tag('Track Item') %>
  <% end %>
</p>
```

And in TrackerController:

```
class TrackerController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def track
    puts "navigating to track view"
    @id = params[:id]
    redirect_to "/tracker/track/#{@id}" 
  end
end
```

But I'm getting the error:
The page isn't redirecting properly - Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

However, if I link directly to a page like this:

```
<%= link_to("Track item 2", {:action => 'track', :id => '6969'}) %>
```

It works fine. Here is my output when I run `rake routes`:

```
Calvins-Air:trckr Calvino$ rake routes
root  /                                      tracker#index
      /:controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format) :controller#:action
```

If I use a different action, I can't use the instance variable I set in the controller.

New Controller Code:

```
  def track
    puts "navigating to track view"
  end

  #redirects to track after retrieving the url parameters
  #want a url parameter so users can link to the page
  def track_helper
    @id = params[:id]
    redirect_to "/tracker/track/#{@id}"
  end
```

But then the track view, @id can't be accessed:

```
<h1>Tracker#track</h1>
<p>This page will be used to view an items details</p>
<p><b>Item id: <%= @id %> </b></p>

<%= link_to("Back to index" , {:action => 'index'}) %>
```

EDIT: Fixed that last error by declaring the @id variable in the track action. Fixed code:

```
 def track
    puts "navigating to track view"
    @id = params[:id]
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that's because your redirect path is handled by the same action(and controller) from where you are sending this request. You can either create a new action for it or route this to a different handler.

Comment: So this fixed the error. But now I can't access the instance variable on the redirected page. I've edited my post with the new comment.

Comment: Answered my own question. Thanks!